# Vector/SVG data of World / Country Boundaries?

Tags: gis, visualization

I'm developing an OpenGL application. I need to have a model of planet earth spinning around (with the waters in blue, the land in green). My question is not dealing with the OpenGL / graphics ... but with the data.

Where can I get this data? (Of the boundaries of the various countries). Bonus points if you also know where I can get elevation data for each country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get elevation from [SRTM data](http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/) from NASA. For country boundaries, I would download a shp file from a site like [Geocommunity](http://data.geocomm.com/editorspicks/data_world11.html).  You then can find one of the many open source shp file parsers to parse the data.  Another possiblity for elevation data is [DEM data](http://data.geocomm.com/dem/).  [Here's a discusion](http://freegeographytools.com/2007/converting-digital-elevation-models-to-shapefiledxf-contours) on working with DEM data.  You can also find [tile data from Nasa](http://onearth.jpl.nasa.gov/).

Answer (score 1):

For boundaries you might want to have a look at one of those:

- [Natural earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/)
- [Global Admin Areas](http://www.gadm.org/world)
- [Geonames](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/allCountries.zip)